# Phonebook Alphabetical Sorting according to the field First Name

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, javafx

I am trying to get my JavaFx application of a phone book in order to sort alphabetically the contacts list according to the first name. However, the existing loop is not listing the names in the correct order. Here is the sorting method:

```
 public static void sortContactList() {
        try {
        for (int i = 0; i < contactList.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; i < contactList.length; j++) {
                if ((contactList[j].first.toCharArray()[0]) < (contactList[i].first.toCharArray()[0])) {
                    Entry tmp = contactList[j];
                    contactList[j] = contactList[i];
                    contactList[i] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException exc) {}
}
```

Below it is shown how the contact list is made up. It is stored in a file with first being the person's first names as strings:

```
class Entry {
public String first, last, number, note;
}
public class Phonebookfor1510 {
public static Entry[] contactList;
public static int num_entries;
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    int i;
    char C;
    String code, Command;
    contactList = new Entry[200];
    num_entries = 0;
```

The rest of my code works with it. I am just wondering why it is not sorting the list of values alphabetically. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Why not just use `Arrays#sort`?  Even if we fix your code, you are only sorting based on the first character.

Comment: I'd say it doesn't sort correctly because you're algorithm is incorrect. It doesn't look right to me. Unless you really have to implement sort yourself, why not use a standard algorithm, eg. [Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the second for loop will never end without a `NullPointerException`. You are increasing `j`, but checking for `i<contactList`.

You could use `Arrays.sort()` in this case.

Comment: I'm very new to java and I tried to enter the array but it's stuck in the list for example i'm trying this : Arrays.sort(contactList[].first, 0, num_entries); and it brings up and error and I'm not sure why. Thanks for the info about the metho!!

Comment: Anyway, your code should work if you change the head of the second for loop to  `for (int j = i + 1; j < contactList.length; j++) `

It is not the fastest way. But it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

The Best thing You can Do is Use TreeSet. Like the given example

```
TreeSet<String> stringSet = new TreeSet<>();
        stringSet.add("Mummy");
        stringSet.add("Mahima");
        stringSet.add("Gaurav");
        stringSet.add("Naresh");
        stringSet.add("Bhawna");

        for(String s : stringSet) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

**Output :** 
Bhawna
Gaurav
Mahima
Mummy
Naresh

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this sample code:

```
public class Entry implements Comparable<Entry>{
    private Long id;
    private String fullName;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public int compareTo(Entry other) {
        if(other==null) throw new NullPointerException();
        /*
        -1 : phonenumber of current entry is smaller that other
        0  : phonenumber of current entry is equal to other
        +1 : phonenumber of current entry is greater than other
         */
        return (this.getFullName().compareTo(other.getPhoneNumber()));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Entry[] entriesArray = getEntriesArrayListFromSomewhere();
        Arrays.sort(entriesArray);
    }

   //getters ans setters
}
```